# Count 'Yes' from column K where year is 2014 in column B?

Tags: excel, formula, countif

I am trying to create an excel formula which will count all of the occurrences of the word 'Yes' in my column K where the year of the date in column B is '2014'.

```
Column B           Column K
01/02/2014         Yes
03/04/2014         No
06/01/2014         Yes
08/02/2015         Yes
```

So I know how to get the year from my date in column b

=YEAR(B:B)

But now I want to combine this and put it into a countif formula which will count all of the yes's in my column k where the year in column b is 2014.

here's what I've tried to put together:

```
=COUNTIF(K:K="Yes",YEAR(A:A)=2014))
```

This doesn't work, please can someone show me where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR($A$2:$A$5)=2014),--($B$2:$B$5="Yes"))
```

[image]

To make it more dynamic, i.e.: get the criteria from the matching row data, change the formula to this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR($A$2:$A$5)=YEAR(A2)),--($B$2:$B$5=B2))
```

**EDIT:**
Maybe this is what we need, paste below formula to `C2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR($E$2:$E$5)=A2),--($F$2:$F$5=B2))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I need as I am having to use this formula all they way down the page, I just waned one formula in one cell which would count the yes's in column k where the year of the dates in column b = 2014

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but this would work :
Create 3rd column with formula : `=YEAR(A2) & B2`
And to get your count use : `=COUNTIF(C2:C5; "2014Yes")`

Comment: I really don't want to create a 3rd column I would prefer to keep it all in one formula